# How to allow certain extension types in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, file-extension

I have 3 file inputs that I've been trying to secure, but I haven't had success.
I need these file inputs to only take **jpeg, jpg, png,** and **gif**. I know **the mime type is not reliable to use, therefore, I would like to no longer use  it**. And if there is a cleaner or faster way to do this in **PHP procedure way** than **IF statements**, would be better.

*HTML code*

```
<input type="file" name="index_desl_Cfile1" class="upload-image" />
<input type="file" name="index_desl_Cfile2" class="upload-image" />
<input type="file" name="index_desl_Cfile3" class="upload-image" />
```

*PHP code*

```
$target_dir = "../site_images/";

$index_deslC1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["name"]);
$index_deslC2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["name"]);
$index_deslC3 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["name"]);

// Check if file already exists
 $src1 = 'http://localhost//397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC1;
 $src2 = 'http://localhost/397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC2;
 $src3 = 'http://localhost/397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC3;    
if (@getimagesize($src1)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists 1. ";
    $uploadOk = 0;

}
 else if (@getimagesize($src2)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists 2. ";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
 else if (@getimagesize($src3)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists 3. ";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

    $imageFileTypeC1 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["type"];
    $imageFileTypeC2 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["type"];
    $imageFileTypeC3 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["type"];

    $allowed_types = array('image/jpg','image/png','image/jpeg','image/gif');

    if (!in_array($imageFileTypeC1, $allowed_types)) {

            echo "ILLEGAL FILE TYPE 1";
            $uploadOk = 0;

        }
    else if (!in_array($imageFileTypeC2, $allowed_types)) {

            echo "ILLEGAL FILE TYPE 2";
            $uploadOk = 0;

        }
    else if (!in_array($imageFileTypeC3, $allowed_types)) {

            echo "ILLEGAL FILE TYPE 3";
            $uploadOk = 0;

        }           
         else {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo " Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC1)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
  else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC2)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
  else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC3)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
```

It will have more than 3 file inputs.

Comment: are you saying the above doesn't work?

Comment: It might look like it does, but it doesn't work. This is what I get as error - ILLEGAL FILE TYPE 2 Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Comment: whats in `print_r($_FILES);` will ther always be 3 ?

Comment: ERROR: ILLEGAL FILE TYPE 2Array ( [index_desl_Cfile1] => Array ( [name] => Capture.PNG [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php5E56.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 21861 ) [index_desl_Cfile2] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) [index_desl_Cfile3] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Comment: so no 2 or 3 is ever uploaded, so you need to check there is a file, befror checking its type

Comment: Well, the user has the option to upload to 3 different inputs or just one and  yes, it will be more than 3. Let me add the code where I check if  a file exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Instead of using the **if statements** where I check the file types, I used the **switch statement** and it worked like a charm!

Here is all the code...

```
$target_dir = "../site_images/";

$index_deslC1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["name"]);
$index_deslC2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["name"]);
$index_deslC3 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["name"]);

// Check if file already exists
$src1 = 'http://localhost//397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC1;
$src2 = 'http://localhost/397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC2;
$src3 = 'http://localhost/397/admin/site_images/'.$index_deslC3;    
if (@getimagesize($src1)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists 1. ";
$uploadOk = 0;

}
else if (@getimagesize($src2)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists 2. ";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
else if (@getimagesize($src3)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists 3. ";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

$imageFileTypeC1 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["type"];
$imageFileTypeC2 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["type"];
$imageFileTypeC3 = $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["type"];

$allowed_types = array('image/jpg','image/png','image/jpeg','image/gif');

switch ($allowed_types) {
    case in_array($imageFileTypeC1, $allowed_types):
      echo "GOOD 1!";
      $uploadOk = 1;
    break;
    case in_array($imageFileTypeC2, $allowed_types):
      echo "GOOD 2!";
      $uploadOk = 1;
    break;
    default:
      echo "ILLEGAL FILE TYPE";
      $uploadOk = 0;
}

 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo " Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC1)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile1"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC2)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile2"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["tmp_name"], $index_deslC3)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["index_desl_Cfile3"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
```